# How to add a character to both sides of a word of a string in java?

Tags: java

I am writing small program that the user will enter a word, and the word should return with a hyphen between each letter and < sign to the left and > to the right of that word.

For example: hello should return as <-H-e-l-l-o->

so i have tried to write the following code:

import java.util.*;

public class Word {

```
public static void main( String[] args) {

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Write a word:");

     String s1;
     s1 = input.nextLine();

     System.out.print("<-");

     for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {

         System.out.print(s1.charAt(i) + "-");

         System.out.print(">");

    }

}
```

}

But the output add a > sign after each letter of the word.

Comment: Then you should not have the output of `>` in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [comment by QBrute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528405/how-to-add-a-character-to-both-sides-of-a-word-of-a-string-in-java#comment70262742_41528405):

> Then you should not have the output of `>` in the loop?

If you simply move it after the loop, your code will work.

To answer the question in your title ("How to ..."), here are 5 different ways, where the first one (`usingPrint`) is the corrected version of your code. There are of course more ways than this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    usingPrint("Hello");
    System.out.println(usingReplaceAll("Hello"));
    System.out.println(usingStringJoiner("Hello"));
    System.out.println(usingStringBuilder("Hello"));
    System.out.println(usingCharArray("Hello"));
}
private static void usingPrint(String input) {
    System.out.print("<-");
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        System.out.print(input.charAt(i) + "-");
    System.out.println(">");
}
private static String usingReplaceAll(String input) {
    return "<" + input.replaceAll("", "-") + ">";
}
private static String usingStringJoiner(String input) { // Java 8+
    StringJoiner buf = new StringJoiner("-", "<-", "->");
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        buf.add(input.substring(i, i + 1));
    return buf.toString();
}
private static String usingStringBuilder(String input) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder("<");
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        buf.append('-').append(input.charAt(i));
    return buf.append("->").toString();
}
private static String usingCharArray(String input) {
    char[] buf = new char[input.length() * 2 + 3];
    int j = 0;
    buf[j++] = '<';
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        buf[j++] = '-';
        buf[j++] = input.charAt(i);
    }
    buf[j++] = '-';
    buf[j++] = '>';
    return new String(buf);
}
```

*Output*

```
<-H-e-l-l-o->
<-H-e-l-l-o->
<-H-e-l-l-o->
<-H-e-l-l-o->
<-H-e-l-l-o->
```

Comment: Thanks for these different ways. i have tried it with StringBuilder and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `StringBuilder` to add the characters.

So start with a `StringBuilder` that contains "<-".

Then you iterate through the String and for each character you:

1. add the character to the `StringBuilder`
2. add "-" to the `StringBuilder`

At the end of the loop you can then add ">"

Then return the `String` from the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: In what way does this address the problem cited in the question?

Comment: @ScottHunter, it gives the OP a proper algorithm to use to create the method.

Comment: It might *now*; the original didn't even come close.

Comment: @camickr First address the problem, *then* offer a better solution

Comment: @AndrewLiq, it does address the initial problem. If you follow the logic you would see what should be done inside the loop and what should be done outside the loop. People need to develop some basic problem solving the skills by writing down the steps to the problem.

Comment: @camickr i have tried StringBuilder and it worked fine.

Comment: @jack, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it works!

```
 import java.util.*;

    public class Word {

    public static void main( String[] args) {

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Write a word:");

         String s1;
         s1 = input.nextLine();

         System.out.print("<-");

         for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {

             System.out.print(s1.charAt(i) + "-");
      }
             System.out.print(">");

    }
    }
```

Comment: printing > out of the loop solved the problem, thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to put the statement to print right end sign ">" into *for* loop?

In my opinion, to get the correct output that you require, I think the statement to print sign ">" is put after *for* statement, but not write into *for* statement.

This is simple way to solve your issue.

Comment: printing ">" out of the loop solved the problem, thanx.